# Sort list of dictionary by date if date is available else by uid

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, sorting

I want to sort list of dictionary by "date" if date is not 0 available in the dictionary else by "uid".

Below is the list of dictionary

```
students = [{"name": "Student1", "JoiningDate": 2012, "uid": 5}, {"name": "Student2", "JoiningDate": 2008, "uid":10},
               {"name": "Student3", "JoiningDate": 2017, "uid": 1}]
```

I have used below code but it is completely wrong.

```
sorted_set = sorted(set_of_students(key=lambda item:item['JoiningDate']) if item["JoiningDate"] != 0 else (key=lambda item:item['uid']))
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you wish to aggregate dictionaries where date equals 0 at the end of your result, sorting by `uid`.

Under this assumption, you can use a tuple key as below:

```
students = [{"name": "Student1", "JoiningDate": 2012, "uid": 5},
            {"name": "Student2", "JoiningDate": 2008, "uid":10},
            {"name": "Student3", "JoiningDate": 2017, "uid": 1},
            {"name": "Student4", "JoiningDate": 0, "uid":15},
            {"name": "Student5", "JoiningDate": 2010, "uid":6},
            {"name": "Student6", "JoiningDate": 0, "uid": 3}]

res = sorted(students, key=lambda x: (x['JoiningDate']==0, x['JoiningDate'], x['uid']))

print(res)

[{'JoiningDate': 2008, 'name': 'Student2', 'uid': 10},
 {'JoiningDate': 2010, 'name': 'Student5', 'uid': 6},
 {'JoiningDate': 2012, 'name': 'Student1', 'uid': 5},
 {'JoiningDate': 2017, 'name': 'Student3', 'uid': 1},
 {'JoiningDate': 0, 'name': 'Student6', 'uid': 3},
 {'JoiningDate': 0, 'name': 'Student4', 'uid': 15}]
```

Comment: thanks for your help. It works. can you please explain.. I am assuming x['JoiningDate']==0, x['JoiningDate'], x['uid'])
if joiningDate is 0 then consider joiningDate else uid which is wrong